# How to compare ordered logistic nested models?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, model-selection, nested-models

Let's say that I have a full and a restricted model that looks like this:

```
Full<- polr(Y ~ X1+X2+X3+X4, data=data, Hess = TRUE,  method="logistic")

Restricted<- polr(Y ~ X1+X2+X3, data=data, Hess = TRUE,  method="logistic")
```

I want to conduct F-tests to determine whether the information from the `X4`variable statistically improves our understanding of Y.

What command is convenient for carrying out this test for logistic regression? Is it `aov()`? 
For example:

```
summary(aov(Y ~ X1+X2+X3+X4)) #Full model
summary(aov(Y ~ X1+X2+X3)) #Restricted model
```

In linear regression case this would be the way to do it, I am not sure for ordered logistic regression...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the likelihood ratio test. Twice the difference in log likelihood (larger minus smaller) will be approximately $\chi^2_1$ distributed in this case. Generally, the degrees on freedom equals the number of additional predictors in the larger model.

Comment: Thanks for this. Why is the LRT better than the F-test? This source http://www.stat.ncsu.edu/people/bloomfield/courses/st430-514/slides/MandS-ch04-sec13-14.pdf seems to prefer the F-test

Comment: The f test only applies to linear models, which ordered logistic is not.